# Update the same row multiple times

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to increment a row when in the form's the item is selected. I know that doing an update statement does what I ask but my question is: if in the form there is 5 or 10 fields that the user can choose at the same time the same item, How can I update the same row in the same time to save the X number of times that the same item was chosen?

My table is this:

```
---materials--- (table name)
id (int)
mat_name (varchar)
quantity (int)
used  (int)
existence (int)
```

The row I need to raise with "1" when the item was choose is "used"

In the table of "materials" there are like 100 of items like:

onions,
pears,
broccoli,
etc..

So the idea is when some item was selected for whatever in the table that item will be increment in 1 in the row "used" and with a simple substraction show how much quantity of every item remains in existence

my query could look something like this:

```
$statement = "UPDATE materials
    SET used = :used,
    WHERE mat_name = :mat_name";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($statement);
$stmt->bindParam(':used', $_POST['used'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':mat_name', $_POST['mat_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You probably need `SET used = used + :used` to update the value of `used`. Your current code ignores the previous value of `used` and puts a new value in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update a row in a table like this, giving the columns you want changed and the new value for each. Notice that you can refer to the column's previous value, as `used = used+1` does.

```
UPDATE materials
   SET used=used+1, 
       recent_user='personsName'
 WHERE mat_name = 'apple'
```

You can increment a number in multiple rows in a single `UPDATE` query like this.

```
UPDATE materials
  SET used = used + 1
WHERE mat_name IN ('apple', 'banana', 'kumquat')
```

You can update more than one column in multiple rows, too. Simply give a list of columns to be updated along with their new values. For example,

```
UPDATE materials
   SET used=used+1, 
       recent_user='personsName'
 WHERE mat_name IN ('apple', 'banana', 'kumquat')
```

Comment: Ok so if the form have 10 fields and 5 of them was selected for onion's , four fileds for apple's and one was for broccoli with this sentence will be works : `UPDATE materials
  SET used = used + 1
WHERE mat_name = :mat_name`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you'll either need to run that `UPDATE` query you wrote once for each item to be updated, or use the `IN (item,item,item)` form I have shown, or some other `WHERE` clause that can match multiple rows.

Comment: can you help me where I have the error? `try{
$tevent = '1';
 $sql = "UPDATE materials SET used = used + 1 WHERE mat_name IN (:pro , :pro1 , :pro2 , :pro3 , :pro4 , :pro5 , :pro6 , :pro7 , :pro8 , :pro9)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':used', $tevent, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':mat_name', $_POST['mat_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
 echo " ";
 }catch(PDOException $exception){ 
 echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
 }` and I tried  with `
$stmt->bindParam(':mat_name', $_POST['pro'], PDO::PARAM_STR);`until pro 9 without success

Comment: always show me this warning `Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Comment: The number of bind variables in the query must be the same as the number you use in bindParam. This should be in is own question.

Comment: yes there are 10 fields in the form with name pro, pro1, pro2, etc.. in those fields input with a filter script show the vegetable when the user start typing in everyone... in some cases only 4 or 6 fields are with data when is submited

Comment: Hi I already do it! (at least a part) when some item like per example apple is added two or three times in the table name was saved it one time...per example there is 5 apple and in the form is saved it three times, it need to be saved 5+3=8 not 5+1=6 .... can you help me with this    Best Regards!