# Update one field multiple times in form

Tags: mysql

I still have issue with my previous question [Update the same row multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480811/update-the-same-row-multiple-times)
 because I can't know how update it in the query... Ollie Jones like Axiac showed me the variable `set field + 1` but I tried to implement without success... I will try to explain what I need to update in that field in the table materials.

I have two tables:

```
---materials--- (table name)
id (int)
mat_name (varchar)
quantity (int)
used  (int)
existence (int)
```

And

```
---store--- (table name)
id_store (int)
pro1 (varchar) // with a filter script show the mat_name in materials table
pro2 (varchar) // with a filter script show the mat_name in materials table
pro3 (varchar) // with a filter script show the mat_name in materials table
pro4 (varchar) // with a filter script show the mat_name in materials table
.....
    pro10 (varchar) // with a filter script show the mat_name in materials table
    observations (varchar)
    date (datetime)
```

Per example I select in the form onion, potato, broccoli, onion (in the fields pro1, pro2, pro3 an so on) and them push the button save it.. that data will save into the `store` Database and update in the `materials` Database too, in this example the two onions, one potato and one broccoli in the field `used` in `materials` db the numbers of each product and add it to the previous data

The query I am using is this:

```
try{
    $sql = "UPDATE materials SET used = used + 1 WHERE mat_name IN (:pro1 , :pro2 , :pro3 , :pro4 , :pro5 , :pro6 , :pro7 , :pro8 , :pro9, :pro10)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':used', $_POST[' '], PDO::PARAM_STR); **// Here I don't know what need to put**
$stmt->bindParam(':material', $_POST[' '], PDO::PARAM_STR); **// Here I don't know what need to put**
$stmt->execute();
    echo " ";
    }catch(PDOException $exception){ 
    echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question/problem is?

Comment: @dan08 well in this part `$stmt->bindParam(':used', $_POST[' '], PDO::PARAM_STR); **// Here I don't know what need to put**
$stmt->bindParam(':material', $_POST[' '], PDO::PARAM_STR); **// Here I don't know what need to put**`I don't know what put inside of ` $_POST[' ']`

Comment: The keys in  `$_POST` will be the names of your form elements. To get a view of what `$_POST` contains add `print_r($_POST)` before your try block.

Comment: @dan08, yes I know that `$_POST['pro1'], $_POST['pro2'], $_POST['pro3']` and so on but in the table name `materials` I have only two fields (different to store table name that have the 10 pro fields) used which is the field to update and materials which is the field to compare the product name in every pro field in the form (pro1, pro2, pro3, pro4...pro10)